# what is Constructor using objects as parameter?

Tags: java, class

I have the below code as i understand it should return output like `TRUE` & `FALSE` but unfortunately when i run this program its returning output ike `False`  & `False` output. Why?

Please help me by explaining the meaning of this program.

```
//How to pass   objects as parameter in constructor
package learn.basic.corejava;

public class Test {

    int a,b;

    public Test(int i,int j) { 
        a=i;
        b=j;
    }

    boolean check(Test tobj)
    {
        if(tobj.a == a && tobj.b == b)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         Test obj1=new Test(100, 22);
         Test obj2=new Test(100, 22);
         Test obj3=new Test(-1, -1);

         System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2));
         System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj3)); 
    }

}
```

**Why i think "it should return `True` & `False`**

- Because the value of `obj1` are set to the constructor & similarly the values of `obj2` also set to the constructor , since in first comparision they both are same so i think it should return `true` for this comparison `obj1.equals(obj2)`

Comment: Why do you think it should return False and True?

Comment: It should be `System.out.println(obj1.check(obj2));` You did'nt override equals, but created a new method called check.

Comment: Why would you expect `obj1.equals(obj2)` to invoke `check(Test)` method?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Because the value of `obj1` are set to the constructor & similarly the values of `obj2` also set to the constructor , since in first comparision they both are same so i think it should return `true` for this comparison `obj1.equals(obj2)`

Comment: Where is the `equals` method implemented for `Test` class? Where does it actually check that the objects are equals?

Comment: @rani You're using the default implementation of equals.

Comment: @ZouZou you said `System.out.println(obj1.check(obj2));` must be usefull coment but i could not understand.. What does it mean..?

Comment: @rani You defined a method check which checks if you two objects' attribute your comparing have the same value. But you're using equals() to check if your two objects are equals in your main. Since you didn't overrid this method in your test class, it uses the default implementation of the Object class. That's it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis As i know `equals` checks if both  are equal or not . So simply i written `System.out.println(obj1.check(obj2));` for checking purpose.  so did you mean that i have to write a new method called `equals` and there i have to write code for checking & printing true or false?

Comment: `equals` is a method implemented in the `Object` class which is the parent class of every class in Java. If you don't override the method, then the default implementation will be used.

Comment: @ZouZou why overiding of `equals` method is necessary? And did u mean i have to write a new mthod in this class like this ->  `public void equals(Test obj){//Code logic}`

Comment: @rani Read the part _"The equals() Method"_ : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis no i got it , in my program i made a small mistake  . `just i renamed my method check to equals & now i am getting correct output`. Actually i made  a silly mistake. You were right as you said above in your comment `Where is the equals method implemented for Test class? Where does it actually check that the objects are equals?`

Comment: @ZouZou your fist comment for this question is right. thanks its a small mistake

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis 1 help from your side. Could you please tell me the core idea like "how you learnt java?" What should i do & follow to learn java , i want to be like you in CORE JAVA?  I am trying for job since 6 months whenever i go to interview they reject me. So i want to learn java nicely like you.

Comment: This is not appropriate for SO (don't ask a question, go to the chat and ask there). I learned Java in college. After that, I think my main source of java knowledge was looking at source code of various libraries. Don't do that unless you really understand the syntax and principles of OOP languages, like polymorphism.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis okay one thing i learn from your side is " looking at source code of various libraries". Currently  i am learning syntax and practicing all basic of java. i will check all libraries code after learning syntax.

Comment: One step at a time. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To test if two objects are identical (that is: whether they're one and the same), use `==`, not `equals()`. With the sample input in the question this would print `true` and `false`, *assuming* that you have implemented `equals()`:

```
System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2)); // true
System.out.println(obj1 == obj2);      // false
```

Or perhaps more interesting:

```
Test obj1 = new Test(100, 22);
Test obj2 = new Test(100, 22);
Test obj3 = obj2;

System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2)); // true
System.out.println(obj1 == obj2);      // false
System.out.println(obj2 == obj3);      // true
System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj3)); // true
```

Now back to your question. The problem lies in the fact that you haven't properly implemented `equals()`, which tests for value *equality* between objects, and that's what you're interested in. For the code in the question, a correct implementation of `equals()` would look like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)  // are the objects identical?
        return true;
    if (obj == null)  // is the other object null?
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) // do the objects have the same class?
        return false;
    Test other = (Test) obj; // cast other object
    if (a != other.a) // is the `a` field equal in both objects?
        return false;
    if (b != other.b) // is the `b` field equal in both objects?
        return false;
    return true;      // ok, the objects are equal :)
}
```

Comment: `==` checks that two objects are same object. Word "identical" is very misleading, I afraid.

Comment: @Nikolay The correct technical term is: `==` tests for reference _identity_. So yes, it's correct to say that `==` tests whether two bjects are _identical_

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis right you are. I added an implementation in my answer, thanks!

Comment: @rani ok, feel free to ask any questions you need :)

Comment: Looks like you know java very well. Could you please tell me the core idea like how you learn java? What should i do & follow to learn java?  I am looking for job since 6 months whenever i go to interview they reject me. So i want to learn it fast.

Comment: @rani hard question :P grab any book or on-line tutorial for the basics, but the key is practicing a lot, writing code, reading code, perhaps joining an open source project...

Comment: @ÓscarLópez :)  currently i grabbed this book(http://www.amazon.in/gp/reader/0071606300/ref=sib_dp_pt#reader-link)  .  And also i also started practicing code in Computer.  An also i joined one institution for little extra learning. In my country now its 4.AM but still i am practing...

Comment: @rani that's the spirit :) a lot of hard work will get you very far

Answer (score 1):

Well first things first you are calling the equals to function not the check function. So you could change that. Or you could change the check to equals and override the object equals to.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
         Test obj1=new Test(100, 22);
         Test obj2=new Test(100, 22);
         Test obj3=new Test(-1, -1);

         System.out.println(obj1.check(obj2));
         System.out.println(obj1.check(obj3)); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the equals method not the check method...the check method doesn't exist on Object class

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

please note: if you override equals Java's specification requires to override the hashCode method too.

Alternatively you can use your own check.